# How to modify column index of a template field in a gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a `gridview` with both `autogenerated columns` and `template field`. 
I am using `GridView.RowCreated` to move my template field to the rightmost side. However, what I need to do is to put it in between `HOUR` column and `NAME` column.

**Is it possible to insert the template field column in between auto-generated columns?**

**VB.NET**

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("Hour", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))

'fill table

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

**RowCreated code**

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated
    Dim row As GridViewRow = e.Row
    ' Intitialize TableCell list
    Dim columns As New List(Of TableCell)()
    For Each column As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
        'Get the first Cell /Column
        Dim cell As TableCell = row.Cells(0)
        ' Then Remove it after
        row.Cells.Remove(cell)
        'And Add it to the List Collections
        columns.Add(cell)
    Next

    row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray())
End Sub
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid">
<RowStyle Font-Bold="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control" ShowHeader="True" Visible="True"
          ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<HeaderTemplate> View </HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="B_SHOW" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/MA/Images and Icons/zoom-icon.png" Width="22px" Height="22px" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CommandName="EXECUTE_QUERY"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>                 
</Columns>                                              
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arrange the Columns of a GridView in any order.

Use the [**`CloneFields()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcollection.clonefields%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create a copy of your Columns. After that clear the GridView's Column collection and re-add the Columns in required order.

```
Dim columnsCollection As DataControlFieldCollection =    
                                         GridView1.Columns.CloneFields()
GridView1.Columns.Clear()

    ' Now add the Columns one by one in any order
    ' add 3rd column as the FIRST Column
    GridView1.Columns.Add(columnsCollection(3))
   '  Add 7th Column as Second Column
   GridView1.Columns.Add(columnsCollection(7))
```

You can also use `Insert()` Method, if need be::

```
GridView1.Columns.Insert(0, columnsCollection(3))
```

Comment: Hi! I only just tried your method now. However, when I tried cloning the gridview's fields, I am only getting the count equivalent to the template field column count. Thus, I get the error: "Index out of range. Index must be a non-negative integer"